# How can I do simple math with a generic INumber in .NET 7 / C#11?

Tags: c#, generics, c#-11.0, .net-generic-math

I like to program a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) function using a class with a generic data type bound to an `INumber` in .NET 7/C# 11 as

```
public class Histogram<TValue> where TValue : INumber<TValue>

public List<KeyValuePair<int,  int>> CalcHistogram(List<TValue> Values, TValue CorrectValue, TValue BinSize)
{
        // ...

        foreach (TValue value in Values)
        {
                // version 1
                // calc bin number as TValue type
                TValue bn = (value - CorrectValue) / BinSize;

                // round to nearest int without Math.Round
                int binNumber = bn < 0 ? (int)(bn - 0.5) : (int)(bn + (TValue)0.5);

                // version 2
                // calc bin number
                int binNumber2  = (int)Math.Round((value - CorrectValue) / BinSize, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

                // ....
```

But I get multiple errors I don't understand:

1. `bn < 0` results in a CS0019 error (Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'int'), although I thought that `IComparable` should do that. Casting 0 to `TValue` does not work as in 3.
2. `bn - 0.5` results in a CS0019 error (Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'double'), although I thought I could subtract two "numbers".
3. `(TValue)0.5` results in a CS0030 error (Cannot convert type 'double' to 'TValue'), although I thought that casting a double to a "number" should be possible, after all, `double` implements `INumber`.
4. `(binNumber * BinSize)` results in a CS0019 error (Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'TValue').
5. `(int)Math.Round((value - CorrectValue) / BinSize, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` results in CS1503 (Argument 1: cannot convert from TValue to decimal) and CS1503 (Argument 2: cannot convert from System.MidpointRouting to int).

Can't I use the generic `INumber` as a "number" and do whatever I could do with a `float` or a `double` like casting, arithmetic operations +-*/, comparing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic math allows to operate on numbers of the same type (check out the interfaces, they are usually defined using curiously recurring template pattern like `INumber<TSelf> : IComparable<TSelf>`), so you need to match types for operations.

> `bn < 0` results in a CS0019 error (Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'int'), although I thought that IComparable should do that

This can be `bn < TValue.Zero`

> `bn - 0.5` results in a CS0019 error (Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TValue' and 'double'), although I thought I could subtract two "numbers".

This one - `bn - TValue.CreateChecked(0.5)` (or other `INumber<TSelf>.CreateX` methods)

> `(TValue)0.5`

`TValue.CreateChecked` again

> `(binNumber * BinSize)`

`(TValue.CreateChecked(binNumber) * BinSize)`

> `(int)Math.Round((value - CorrectValue) / BinSize, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

rounding is defined for `IFloatingPoint<TSelf>` - [`IFloatingPoint<TSelf>.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ifloatingpoint-1.round?view=net-7.0)

And "cast" from the `TValue` to `int` can be done like this:

```cs
int.CreateChecked(binNumber)
```

Note that `CreateChecked` will throw in case of overflow.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about the CreateXX methods. Now with the proper way to cast, I can even use the Math.Round method again.

Comment: @Qrt was glad to help! Note that it is not actually casting and can behave a bit differently compared to it (an example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75593871/2501279))