# Generic math how to cast from INumber to a "concrete" type (int/double/etc)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, c#-11.0, .net-generic-math

Suppose we have a generic method which accepts `INumber<T>` and returns `int`:

```cs
// process val and return as int
static int DoSomething<T>(T val) where T : INumber<T> => ...
```

How can the `T` be casted to `int`.

Comment: What if `T` is a double? Would that be an error or is there some conversion you want to define (round, floor, etc.)?

Comment: @DStanley the question description refers to the desired operation as "cast", though exactly the same behavior is not achievable it seems.

Comment: Correct, because you can't actually "cast" a `double` to an `int`. If you use the "cast" syntax at compile time, the compiler actually does a "conversion". If you try to do a cast at runtime it will fail. You need to be explicit on how you want to convert any numeric value to an integer generically.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`INumberBase<TSelf>` defines several `CreateX` operations which can be used to convert generic value to the target one (and vice versa):

```cs
static int DoSomething<T>(T val) where T : INumber<T> => int.CreateChecked(val);
```

- [`INumberBase<TSelf>.CreateChecked<TOther>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createchecked?view=net-7.0)

  > Creates an instance of the current type from a value, throwing an overflow exception for any values that fall outside the representable range of the current type.
- [`INumberBase<TSelf>.CreateSaturating<TOther>(TOther)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createsaturating?view=net-7.0)

  > Creates an instance of the current type from a value, saturating any values that fall outside the representable range of the current type.
- [`INumberBase<TSelf>.CreateTruncating<TOther>(TOther)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumberbase-1.createtruncating?view=net-7.0)

  > Creates an instance of the current type from a value, truncating any values that fall outside the representable range of the current type.

Note that based on method and type pair used the result can differ from casting:

```cs
var d = double.MaxValue - 1;
unchecked
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)d); // -2147483648
    // Console.WriteLine(int.CreateChecked(d)); // throws
}

Console.WriteLine(int.CreateSaturating(d)); // 2147483647
Console.WriteLine(int.CreateTruncating(d)); // 2147483647
```

So use with caution.

[Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ6BuBDMACAEzwF5CB7CAIwBsBTAOgFlsAPANW2oloFokBudNADGAC1rCA1rQLoA3ujxK8cJAE4AFBoCWUYAEoC+wWmV4A9OZXqde+gGEwtbMFr3xUmRqPGLV4KJgZADuAM7oAL7oqpq6wA5OLrQAyi4QYC66AObe+sbRNnEJzq4AKpBQwplQOT4m6ESkCPQAbCYxWnGG+WgdRY4lKWkZwNm5PX12A0nlItW1eSZAA==).

Comment: It's also worth noting that "saturating" means returning the type's min or max value on overflow, and "truncating" typically means returning a bitwise truncation of the value (not necessarily the type's min or max). To illustrate the difference, consider `byte.CreateSaturating(1000)` returns 255, whereas `byte.CreateTruncating(1000)` returns 232, which is 1000 mod 256. Similarly, `byte.CreateSaturating(-1000)` returns 0, and `byte.CreateTruncating(-1000)` returns 24.